# React ejecutar función al cargar

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Tengo una consulta: estoy trabajando con React (clases) y necesito que un button ejecute una funcion al cargar el mismo en el DOM, y no tener que hacerle un click.

Alguien me podria ayudar con un ejemplo? Muchas gracias a todos!

```
import React, { Component } from "react"; 
class Ejemplo extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.funcion = this.funcion.bind(this);
    }

    funcion(){
        console.log("Hola") 
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <button onClick={this.funcion}>Example</button>
        );
    }
}

export default Ejemplo
```

Comment: Puedes mostrar parte de tu codigo? estas trabajando con Clases o con hooks? si es lo segundo puedes hacerlo con [useEffect](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

Comment: Estoy trabajando con clases! Aqui muestro código. Lo agregare a mi pregunta

import React, { Component } from "react"; 
class Ejemplo extends Component {
 constructor(props){
        super(props);
        
        this.funcion = this.funcion.bind(this);
    }

 funcion(){
  console.log("Hola") 
 }

 render(){
  return(

   <button onClick={this.funcion}>Example</button>

   );

  }
}

export default Ejemplo

Answer (score 1):

La forma segun la documentación de react es usar [componentDidMount](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) de React. Tu código quedaría algo así:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
class Ejemplo extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.funcion = this.funcion.bind(this);
    }
    
    componentDidMount() { //<----------------------------
        this.funcion();
    }

    funcion () {
        console.log('Hola');
    }

    render() {
        return <button onClick={this.funcion}>Example</button>;
    }

}
```

Lo que hace `componentDidMount` es que esta función se ejecuta una vez que el componente es unido al árbol de react con todos los componentes. Tambien existe la funcion `componentDidUpdate` el cual se llama cada vez que el componente es rendereado